# how to debug android native c/c++ log Dynamically？

Tags: android, debugging, native

I want to debug some android native c/c++ code, like
`PROJECT_NAME/frameworks/av/media/libaudioclient/AudioTrack.cpp` etc.
but when i use cmd `logcat`, I can't obtain some log level like D & I & V.I try to uncomment `//#define LOG_NDEBUG 0` in top of `AudioTrack.cpp` file, but there are two questions for me,:

one is I want to open or close log dynamically, but in this method I have to comment/unconmment `#define LOG_NDEBUG 0`.
another one is though I uncomment `#define LOG_NDEBUG 0` & endured a long time for `make target-files-package -j12`, It doesn't work as print out log level "Verbose" in terminal.
My question is if there are some way to capture android native c/c++ debug log (include verbose,Info,Debug level) by dynamincally (like read & edit `xxx.xml`)?

Answer (score 2):

you can define **cppFlags** based on which you can toggle logs in native code

app build.gradle -

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags += "-DBUILD_DEBUG"
            }
        }
```

create log constants in native code(possibly in some header file) -

```
#ifdef BUILD_DEBUG

#include<android/log.h>
#define LOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "tag", __VA_ARGS__)

#else

#define LOGV(...)

#endif
```

finally use it like - `LOGV("log to print")`

Comment: Thank u. The question i met is that ALOGV(), ALOGD() isn't my add, it's exist in source android native c++ code like '/frameworks/av/media/libaudioclient/AudioTrack.cpp' , but Verbose & Debug level isn't print out by default(i don't know why), I need this verbose & debug level log for debugging, If I want to open all audio-related android native c/c++ log,include verbose and debug level，so have to edit all c++ file? is there some simple way to open or close log-related ? best wish!

Comment: you are using CMakeLists.txt or Android.mk for ndk build?

Comment: also you might need to add log-lib to enable logging - https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake

Comment: No, It's Android.bp. I want to capture some AudioTrack Verbose log，but use `adb shell `, `logcat | grep -i audiotrack`, there are all about Warning or Info or Error level log. Someone tell me Verbose & Debug Level log  will not print by default, need open it by hand, but  cpp-file-related is too many.I'd like a simeple way to control close/open log related to audio module.

Comment: please upload some code also add some details about your android project

Comment: dynamincally (like read & edit xxx.xml) - my answer points to that where you can set some flags based on buildvariant/flavor and toggle logs on/off based on that